# How to to convert Redux Saga to Observable

Tags: redux-saga, redux-observable

I have to dive into Redux-Observable and my fight is to convert this Sagas

```
function* loadTabs(action) {
  const tabs = yield call(api.fetchTabs)
  yield put(actions.setTabs(tabs))
  const tabId = tabs[0].id
  yield put(actions.selectTab(tabId))
  yield put(actions.loadWidgets(tabId))
}

function* loadWidgets({ tabId }) {
  const widgets = yield call(api.fetchWidgets, tabId)
  yield put(actions.setWidgets(widgets))
  yield put(actions.setDashboardReady(true))
}

/* WATCHER */
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery(types.TABS_REQUESTED, loadTabs)
  yield takeEvery(types.WIDGETS_REQUESTED, loadWidgets)
}
```

into Epics. What I've done is

```
const loadTabs = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.TABS_REQUESTED),
  mergeMap(() => api.fetchTabs()),
  map(tabs => actions.setTabs(tabs))
)

const loadWidgets = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.WIDGETS_REQUESTED),
  mergeMap(() => api.fetchTabs()),
  map(widgets => actions.setWidgets(widgets)),
)

const rootEpic = combineEpics(loadTabs, loadWidgets)
```

"Dispatch chain" should be 'TABS_REQUESTED > setTabs > selectTab > loadWidgets > setDashboardReady'. I've stopped with 
'TABS_REQUESTED > setTabs '

Please kick me forward with missed parts. I'm just overloaded with manual right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is like an eclipse. Stop, think about streams actions-in/actions-out and try again..

So, I've done it like this

```
const loadTabs = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.TABS_REQUESTED),
  mergeMap(() => api.fetchTabs()),
  switchMap(tabs => [
    actions.setTabs(tabs),
    actions.selectTab(tabs[0].id),
    actions.loadWidgets(tabs[0].id)
  ])
)

const loadWidgets = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.WIDGETS_REQUESTED),
  mergeMap(() => api.fetchWidgets()),
  switchMap(widgets => [
    actions.setWidgets(widgets),
    actions.setDashboardReady(true)
  ]),
)
```